# Matplotlib stores .svg different than what is show on screen

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib

Here is an example. The next is what get's stored as a .png and this is how it displays on the screen and it is correct

[image: this is the image that looks right]

and the next is the .svg which is using interpolation for the heatmap

[image]

They are both stored using the next line of code respectively

```
plt.savefig(filename,format='png')
plt.savefig(filename,format='svg')
```

And the next is the code that generates the actual plot

```
def heatmapText(data,xlabels=[],ylabels=[],cmap='jet',fontsize=7):
    '''
    Heatmap with text on each of the cells
    '''


    plt.imshow(data,interpolation='none',cmap=cmap)

    for y in range(data.shape[0]):
        for x in range(data.shape[1]):
            plt.text(x , y , '%.1f' % data[y, x],
                     horizontalalignment='center',
                     verticalalignment='center',
                     fontsize=fontsize
                     )

    plt.gca()
    if ylabels!=[]:
        plt.yticks(range(ylabels.size),ylabels.tolist(),rotation='horizontal')
    if xlabels!=[]:
        plt.xticks(range(xlabels.size),xlabels.tolist(),rotation='vertical')
```

For both plots I used exactly the same function but stored it in different formats. Last, in screen appears correctly (like in the .png).

Any ideas on how to have the .svg to store the file correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_none_vs_nearest.html

[What does matplotlib `imshow(interpolation='nearest')` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473511/what-does-matplotlib-imshowinterpolation-nearest-do)

and

[matplotlib shows different figure than saves from the show() window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490289/matplotlib-shows-different-figure-than-saves-from-the-show-window)

I'm going to recommend trying this with `interpolation=nearest`

The following code gives me identical displayed and saved as svg plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(5, 5)
plt.figure(1)
plt.imshow(A, interpolation='nearest')

plt.savefig('fig',format='svg')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Thanks